# Html tags in javascript alert function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

This is my aspx.cs code:

```
string script = "alert('Dosya/Dosyalar Başarı İle Yüklendi\n " + btnUpload.FileName + " ');";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
```

But it's not working.(no error)
When I delete **\n** operator, its working alert function.
I want to see the fileName below the text

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try using <br/> instead of \n

Comment: must be something related to the platform used, can you output the rendered script tag / file?

Comment: I'm tried. Its working but not fileName below the text.

output:

Dosya/Dosyalar Başarı İle Yüklendi<br/> ag direk.ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  \r\n for a new line:

```
string script = "alert('Dosya/Dosyalar Başarı İle Yüklendi \\r\\n " + btnUpload.FileName + " ');";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
```

Jon Skeet back in 2004 [C# Escape sequences](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx)

```
C# defines the following character escape sequences:

\' - single quote, needed for character literals
\" - double quote, needed for string literals
\\ - backslash
\0 - Unicode character 0
\a - Alert (character 7)
\b - Backspace (character 8)
\f - Form feed (character 12)
\n - New line (character 10)
\r - Carriage return (character 13)
\t - Horizontal tab (character 9)
\v - Vertical quote (character 11)
\uxxxx - Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value xxxx
\xn[n][n][n] - Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value nnnn (variable length version of \uxxxx)
\Uxxxxxxxx - Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value xxxxxxxx (for generating surrogates)
```

Comment: No probs, as you are using a \n in a string you need to escape the \ with another \ so: \n needs to be \\n

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Environment.NewLine` instead of \n.
Example:

```
string script = "alert('Dosya/Dosyalar Başarı İle Yüklendi "+ System.Environment.NewLine + btnUpload.FileName + " ');";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
```

Comment: I am tried but I can not show alert window. I debuged project and I looked script content, its true.
script content: "alert('Dosya/Dosyalar Başarı İle Yüklendi \r\nag direk.DAT ');"